# Как отфильтровать данные из бд с помощью Django ORM

Tags: django, django-orm

Есть следующая модель:

```
class Situation(models.Model):
    lat = models.FloatField()
    lon = models.FloatField()
    hintContent = models.CharField(max_length=400)
    balloonContent = models.CharField(max_length=400)
```

Мне нужно получить во views.py все данные удовлетворяющие условию:
`(lat - x)**2 + (lon - y)**2 < 1.05`(где x и y - вещественные числа).
В документации не нашел как ORM использовать в таком случае.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Попробуйте использовать [Query Expressions](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/models/expressions/)

```
from django.db.models import F

expr = (F('lat') - x) ** 2 + (F('lon') - y) ** 2
situations = Situation.objects.annotate(position=expr).filter(position__lt=1.05)
```

Comment: Ошибку в браузере выдает: FieldError at /points/show
Cannot resolve keyword 'position_lt' into field. Choices are: balloonContent, hintContent, id, lat, lon, position

Comment: @Антон я опечатался на один символ нижнего подчёркивания. Исправил, проверьте.